# Why did Servia become Serbia?

Tags: historical-change, toponyms

Reading contemporary histories of the First World War, I noticed that at the start the nation in the Balkans is referred to as *Servia*, but in numbers published after the back half of 1916, it has turned into *Serbia*.

Is there any particular reason for this?

Consulting [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Serbia%2C%20Servia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSerbia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CServia%3B%2Cc0) gives:-

[image]

which seems to correspond to my observation.

**Edit** Replaced Google NGram with version using capitalised names, as suggested by [Steven Littman](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/109885/steven-littman); the result makes rather more sense.

Comment: Try your ngram using capitalized forms.

Comment: @StevenLittman, That makes a lot more sense. Thank you.

Comment: [*In standard Spanish, the **b** and **v** are identical in terms of pronunciation.*](https://www.thoughtco.com/pronouncing-the-spanish-b-and-v-3079534#:~:text=In%20standard%20Spanish%2C%20the%20b,the%20lips%20touching%20each%20other.) I know Serbia isn't Spain, but isn't it enough to "explain" the orthographic change? Or see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betacism): In historical linguistics, **betacism** (UK: /ˈbiːtəsɪzəm/, US: /ˈbeɪ-/) is a sound change in which [b] (the voiced bilabial plosive, as in bane) and [v] (the voiced labiodental fricative [v], as in vane) are confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a not credible [source](http://www.sciforums.com/threads/servia-serbia.135160/):

> In Ancient Greek, the letter **Beta** was pronounced like English **B**. But in Modern Greek, it's pronounced like English **V**. So "Serbia" became "Servia."

and from another similar [source](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question101736.html) :

> It is called **Serbia** using the **Cyrillic** script and **Servia** when using the **Latin** script.

and finally a credible one could be find at http://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/cgi-bin/paperspast?a=d&d=NOT19150305.2.51

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Servia was the medieval Latin spelling of Serbia according to Etynomline.

[Servia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servia):

> - Historical English term, taken from Greek language, used in relation with Serbia, Serbs or the Serbian language. Wikipedia

[Serb](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Serb):

> - 1813, but in reference to the Wends; 1861 as "native of Serbia," from Serbian Srb, perhaps from a root meaning "man." Serbian is attested from 1848 as a noun, 1876 as an adjective. More common in 19c. was Servian.

[Servian](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Servian&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - 754 (n.), 1723 (adj.), from Medieval Latin Servia, from Serb Serb (see Serb).

Etymonline

Comment: Let me point out that Greek does not distinguish between the sounds /v/ and /b/; the letter β was pronounced /b/ in ancient Greek and is pronounced /v/ in modern Greek.

Answer (score 2):

Servia suggested a false connection with Latin *servus* 'slave', reflected in English *serf* and *servile* (whereas *serve* and *service* have more positive denotations).  Similarly, *Rumânia* was changed to *România* to reflect Romanian *român* 'Roman' rather than *rumân* 'peasant, serf', although too late to affect French *Roumanie* (English has mostly switched from *Roumania* to *Romania*).  In both cases the desire was to avoid a name that sounded like "Serf-land".

Answer (score 1):

Actually the connection with Latin "servus" is from the correct medieval title of the numerous Balkan vassal statelets (Bosnia, Duklya, Zeta, Rashka...) which were generally named by the Roman Catholic Curia as "Regni Serviae" - 'Kingdoms at Service':

[image: Salvatore Mundi, A Petro Bogdano Macedone]

Comment: How do you know that the proper translation of *Regni Serviae* is *Kingdoms of Service* rather than *Kingdoms of the Serbs*? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Serviae) says that *Serviae* is the genitive singular of *Servia* (meaning *Serbia*) in Latin, while [*servitium* and *servitii*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/servitium) are the accusative and genitive singulars of *servitium* (meaning *service*). And [servus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/servus#Latin) means *servant* and not *service*.

Answer (score -2):

Servia is a Latin term imposed by the Vatican for distorting historical facts.
Substitution of letters (v i b, h g j ž etc) is one of the basic methods of blurring facts to distort history.
Тhe only correct name is Serbia (lat/eng) - Србија / Srbija ( српски / srpski )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).